# Creating an encrypted, web-based proxy

Tags: server, proxy

I have moved to Asia where my internet connection is censored and I'd like to check my messages from social sites which happen to be blocked.

As virtually all proxy servers are blocked in this country, I've decided to attempt to roll my own encrypted proxy server. Please note, the key word here is *encrypted*—if the sniffer sees anything like `f@c3b00k` or `w:k:p3d:ia` travelling down the wire I'm had.

I have a website hosted with GoDaddy (Windows with PHP 5.2 & IIS 7).

Is there any way I can set up an encrypted proxy through this service? If so, how, and what open source tools are available to use?

Answer (score 2):

SSH Tunneling your connection will encrypt it, it's simple to setup and encrypted. [Here is the article How To: Surf Securely with an SSH Tunnel](http://paulstamatiou.com/how-to-surf-securely-with-ssh-tunnel)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Php Web Proxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-proxy/) for your needs but I've never used it very much.

You could also try to [set up a Python Proxy with Google App Engine](http://mintywhite.com/software-reviews/security-software/set-proxy-google-app-engine/). The latter works well.